# Using RegionPlot with Root objects

Tags: plotting, regions, regionplot

I am trying to compare two results and illustrate the outcome using `RegionPlot`. However, one of the results is a `Root` (which is calculated using `Solve`), and I find that the `RegionPlot` does not work.

```
RegionPlot[
 Root[839523 β^2 + (1216700 - 3967500 Ns β - 3967500 β^2) #1 + 18750000 #1^3 &, 3] > 0, 
  {β, 0, 1}, {Ns, 0, 2}]
```

How can I address the issue? Is there a way to plot regions containing `Root` object?

Comment: What do you mean by "RegionPlot does not work"? I get [a plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPN2i.png), albeit with a few error messages ...

Comment: I also got error messages, and I guess some values of β or Ns may not result in real numbers of the Root[]. How can I make a constraint of real numbers on RegionPlot[]? or How can I use discrete values to do RegionPlot[]?

Comment: If you don't want to simply silence the error messages with `Quiet`, you can give `RegionPlot` an explicit condition for the real values: `RegionPlot[r ∈ Reals && r > 0, {β, 0, 1}, {Ns, 0, 2}]`. To check only discrete values, you can use `ListPlot`: `Catenate@Table[If[r ∈ Reals && r > 0, {β, Ns}, Nothing], {β, 0, 5}, {Ns, 0, 5}]; ListPlot[%]`.

Comment: “r ∈ Reals” works! Thank you. BTW, why do you know I use r to represent the root expression